# LyX → plain LaTeX export missing image file extensions

Tags: graphics, lyx, export

I have a LyX document which imports an image `bla/bla/bla/image.pdf`. If now I do "File→Export→LaTeX (plain)" it creates a file but it has `\includegraphics{bla/bla/bla/image}` instead of `\includegraphics{bla/bla/bla/image.pdf}`. Don't understand what is the reason for removing the last part of it's name but I'm wondering if it is possible to export the images with the complete name?

Comment: That is actually best practice: You *should* leave those extensions out under LaTeX.

Comment: The reason is that without the extension, LaTeX will try to load image.pdf, but if is not there for some reason,  will try to load image.png  or image.jpg, whereas with the extension will try to load only with what you ordered, and if it is not there, then you 
will have a fatal error. Therefore, it  is usually better to omit the extension.